# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

I am using Yii with PHP and with Sql Server 2008 R2. Can anyone tell me where is the problem ?

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Hold']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Hold'];
            $model->startTimeHour=cc("select code from Lookup where name='$model->startTime' and type='starttime'")->queryScalar();
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Model `$model->startTime` Holds values in Dropdown. Here is the code of that as well.

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'startTime'); ?></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'startTime',$this->_startTime); ?>
            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $form->error($model,'startTime'); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Error on this Line of actionUpdate($id)

```
$model->startTimeHour=cc("select code from Lookup where name='$model->startTime' and type='starttime'")->queryScalar();
```

Error message:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement

Comment: Type=starttime? Are you sure you don't mean time? Plus type is a reserved word, and should be enclosed in square brackets like [type]='starttime'

Comment: @Chuck starttime is int. I try to replace type with [type]='starttime' but still same error

Comment: Try to run the query directly in SQL, if that works, then it the way you are passing the parameters. StartTime should probably be configures as a datetime or data field type. Hard to tell without what your table looks like.

Comment: @Chuck, there is no problem in query i tried it in MSSQL. I think there is something wrong with this name='$model->startTime'. can you tell me is it proper way to access values in dropdown list ??

Comment: Sorry Jani, I'm only good at SQL, I don't use PHP.

Comment: @Chuck Thanks Jani :P

Answer (score 1):

`cc("")`

Question: is your useful alias?

`function cc($sql){
        return Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    }`

I recommend you do not using user input for SQL creation. With validation in the CActiveRecord or without. Binding params is best practice for SQL preparation. This feature allows you do not think about SQL injections and parameters escaping.

**Shortly, replace**

`cc("select code from Lookup where name='$model->startTime' and type='starttime'")->queryScalar();`

to

`cc("select code from Lookup where name = :name and type = 'starttime'")->bindValues([':name' => $model->startTime])->queryScalar();`

But for exact answer i need see the "create statement" for your table Lookup.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lookup](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [code] [int] NULL,
 [type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [position] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lookup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO`

Comment: here is the "create statement" for your table Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for Reply. My Problem has been solved...

Just i change line

```
$model->startTimeHour=cc("select code from Lookup where name='$model->startTime' and type='starttime'")->queryScalar();
```

to

```
$model->startTimeHour=date('H',strtotime($model->startTime));
```